# Read a batch of images in R faster

Tags: r, machine-learning, lapply

I am trying to read in about 20,000 images into R, using the following code :

```
  fill = function(i){
        temp = readImage(as.character(train[i,1]))  
        temp = resize(channel(temp,"grey"),w = 32,h = 32)
  }
  train_im = lapply(1:nrow(train),function(x) fill(x))
```

This block of code takes ~480s to run ,whereas an equivalent code in python runs in about 16 seconds. How can I improve the runtime of my file read-in code in R ?

Comment: Have tips people give here and there on the internet (e.g. https://m-clark.github.io/docs/fastr.html) improved your running time?

Comment: I've used `parLapply`  in the `parallel` library, but the speedup wasn't significant.

Comment: Use the packages magick and imager if possible.